# BizTalk - WMI script to publish the message to message Box

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to publish a message to BizTalk message box using a WMI script . Basically, I am reading the message from non resumable instance. I need to publish this message back to message box instead of saving as file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: No.  The fact that BizTalk has them in a non-resumable state means that BizTalk has determined that it cannot be resubmitted the state it is in.   So even if you managed to get a WMI script to do it, the message would probably still fail.

Comment: Do you know the reason of this non resumable instance?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MQ would probably work for you.  What you can do is 'encode' the properties and write them to the MSMQ Label property for example.

Then, you can use a custom Pipeline Component on the Receive Location that 'decodes' the MQ property and re-writes the message context properties.

I've done similar in the past and it works just fine.